# Laravel orderBy two relations

Tags: laravel, relationship

I want to order some items based on two relations. The first sort parameter is the Country name with reference to the countries table and the second one is to the League name with reference to the leagues table. I have also one third sort parameter which is from the original table.

For the moment I have achieved the sort with only one parameter like that:

```
$prognoses = $this->prognose->where('sport_id', '=', $sport)->where('date', '=', $date)->with('odd')->get()->sortBy(function($prognose) {
    return $prognose->odd->country->name;
});
```

I have tried:

```
$prognoses = $this->prognose->where('sport_id', '=', $sport)->where('date', '=', $date)->orderBy('views', 'DESC')->with('odd')->get()->sortBy(function($prognose) {
    return $prognose->odd->country->name;
});
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can you show what is your expected result?

Comment: The $prognoses must be sorted by 3 parameters 1st country->name, 2nd league->name and 3rd $prognoses->views

Comment: So why dont you use sortBy() method three times?